# How to make my datepicker and timepicker silver?

Tags: android, android-view, android-datepicker

I have date picker like this.

[image]

The one I want is this.

[image: silver picker]

what am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

well it looks like it is a background image. So you need to find a background image then synchronize it to your date picker .

Comment: sorry, that's not a background image. I've the sample project with silver one. There's no background image there and codes are the same.

Comment: @CristyYG your without background datepicker is use latest api use, and second one is old api use. If you set any background then create custom datepicker and timepicker.